# show 2 table in 1 using inner join query

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Hey guys i want to show a table so that table have 2 foreign keys.My *food* and *restaurant* table have *name* column.i tried following codes but i dont know how to show restaurant name and food name different.

```
$sql_select_food = "SELECT food.id,restaurant.name,food.name,food.restaurant_id,foodcategory.title from food INNER join foodcategory ON food.foodcategory_id=foodcategory.id INNER join restaurant ON food.restaurant_id=restaurant.id WHERE food.isActive = 1 ORDER BY food.updateDate DESC";
$result_select_food = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_select_food);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result_select_food) > 0) {
      while ($row_select_food = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_select_food)) {
                        echo "
                            <tr>
                                <td>$row_select_food[name]</td>
                                <td>$row_select_food[name]</td>
                                <td>$row_select_food[title]</td>
                            </tr>
                ";
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use column aliases:

```
SELECT food.id AS food_id, restaurant.name AS restaurant_name, food.name AS food_name ...
```

Then

- `$row_select_food['restaurant_name']` is the name of the restaurant,
- `$row_select_food['food_name']` is the name of the food,
- etc.

Note: `AS` keyword is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Put an alias to the column name and call it later in the code as a column name like :

```
$sql_select_food = "SELECT food.id,restaurant.name as rname, food.name as fname, food.restaurant_id,foodcategory.title from food INNER join foodcategory ON food.foodcategory_id=foodcategory.id INNER join restaurant ON food.restaurant_id=restaurant.id WHERE food.isActive = 1 ORDER BY food.updateDate DESC";
$result_select_food = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_select_food);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result_select_food) > 0) {
      while ($row_select_food = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_select_food)) {
                        echo "
                            <tr>
                                <td>$row_select_food[rname]</td>
                                <td>$row_select_food[fname]</td>
                                <td>$row_select_food[title]</td>
                            </tr>
                ";
                    }
                }
```